# Xcode not showing incompatible pointer type

Tags: xcode, warnings

I'm able to call any method with any arguments without having a warning back. For example:

```
[view addSubview:1]
[view addSubview:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
```

other type of warnings are ok and displayed
why isn't Xcode throwing a warning?

NOTE: it should be a project settings or kind of, because the warning is there in other projects

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Suppose the questions is: why isn't Xcode throwing a warning?

Comment: Are these warnings (not emitted) during editing or compiling?

Comment: Both editing and compiling

Comment: Have you/anyone in your project put some macro to suppress all warnings?

Comment: I don't think so, other warnings are there

Comment: Hate to ask those 2 questions: 1) did you do a 
"clean" and closed/opened xCode. 2) are you sure there is nothing around this code that could trip it - comments hashes, missing semicolons, etc..

Comment: I've had this hassle for a while, sure I cleaned, open/close. The code is actually compiling, therefore no problem of hashes/semicolons

Comment: so it is compiling with no errors and the app is running and not throwing an error (break) on your 1st line?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint between the 2 lines? Does it break when running?

Comment: It breaks when running

Answer (score 1):

Here it is the solution for this question:

**Build Settings -> Implicit Integer to Pointer Conversions**

Take that setting on NO did the trick to have back the warnings